# Reputation graph with non-integer step

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

Reputation graph contains non-integer step when showing small rep changing, e.g. `-2`:

> [image: non-integer rep]

Comment: Why is that a bug?

Comment: @RobertColumbia minimal step should represent minimal possible changing. If it's less than that value - it's useless.