# Reputation graph scale

Tags: support, bug, reputation-graph

When I choose interval with only negative reputation changing then Y range is set to e.g. [-2,0]:

> [image: -2:0]

But if I choose interval with possitive (no matter with or without negative inside) the Y range is set to [0,200]:

> [image: 0:200]

Why in the first case Y range is scaled (with wrong step, as I mentioned [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286999/339911)), but in the second one is not?